# Enter and exit full screen in browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm working with Chrome and I want a simple task. Exiting full screen using code, not `F11` key press.

Here are some documentations about how to implement it:

- https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_exitfullscreen.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API

None of the above methods work. And also lots of non-working answers on Stack Overflow. Please help, I really need to solve this.

---

[Here is CodePen](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/BaoWwGR?editors=1010).

Here is my code:

```js
const button = document.getElementById('exitId');
button.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // JavaScript Code To Exit Fullscreen Goes Here
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) { /* Firefox */
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) { /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) { /* IE/Edge */
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
  
});
```

```html
<button id="exitId">Exit Fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: I had posted an answer with code that's always worked for me, but after I posted it I looked back at your code, and it's very much the same (so I deleted my post). Is there a particular browser that it's not working on for you?

Comment: I'm using chrome and I tested the code in Firefox. None of them work... The issue is that this method doesn't work and I think this is a bug : `document.webkitExitFullscreen();`

Comment: Interesting... what I just discovered is that my code works *if and only if* I use similar code to set full screen mode in the first place. If full screen mode is established using F11 instead, then my code has no effect.

Comment: Yeah, you're right mine too... But this is unfortunate for me not interesting :(

Comment: Also ESC key doesn't work (to exit fullscreen) if we go fullscreen using F11!!! What is going on there?! I HATE F11...

Comment: Hopefully there's a work-around. I'd like to find one now too, now that I'm aware of the difference with F11. But I fear that, in the name of "security", fullscreen invoked via F11 might be treated as a different beast.

Comment: Hmmm... this might not work, but have you tried to trap F11 yourself? Perhaps if you can intercept the F11 keystroke, and go fullscreen with your own code when you do, that might solve the problem.

Comment: Ok I'll try that...

Comment: There is also a fullscreen button in the chrome's menu...

Comment: I can't capture F11 (which wouldn't be a full solution anyway, because of the menu issue you mentioned). Another "interesting" fact is that when entering fullscreen via F11, the `fullscreenchange` event isn't triggered, and `document.fullscreenElement` remains null, leading to the likely conclusion that the F11 version of fullscreen mode is implemented very differently, and may be out of the reach of anything you can do in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

A simple **function** to toggle **fullscreen** in **JavaScript**. It work well on **Firefox** and **Webkit** browsers.

***JavaScript Function***

```js
/**
 * Toggle fullscreen function who work with webkit and firefox.
 * @function toggleFullscreen
 * @param {Object} event
 */
function toggleFullscreen(event) {
  var element = document.body;

  if (event instanceof HTMLElement) {
    element = event;
  }

  var isFullscreen = document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || false;

  element.requestFullScreen = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || function() {
    return false;
  };
  document.cancelFullScreen = document.cancelFullScreen || document.webkitCancelFullScreen || document.mozCancelFullScreen || function() {
    return false;
  };

  isFullscreen ? document.cancelFullScreen() : element.requestFullScreen();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleFullscreen();">Full Screen</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Note that in order to exit full screen using javascript - you have to also enter the fullscreen mode using javascript. If fullscreen was based on F11 - it will not be possible to exit it using javascript.
>
> The reason is that when you enter fullscreen using javascript you actually moving specific part of your document into fullscreen (and not the entire application), while when you are in application-full screen mode - the entire application is in fullscreen.
>
> If you are in fullscreen (application-wise) you still see other tabs. If you are in document/element fullscreen mode - there are no tabs/url/bookmarks bar etc.

Check the following code:

```
<div id="container">  
  <button id="toggle">Toggle Fullscreen</button>
</div>

====

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    } else {
        if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
            if (container.requestFullscreen) {
                container.requestFullscreen();
            }
            else if (container.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                container.mozRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (container.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                container.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            }
            else if (container.msRequestFullscreen) {
                container.msRequestFullscreen();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

You can see a working solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/zpdwL8gt/4/

> Checked on firefox & chrome @ MacOS

Comment: in your code go fullscreen using F11 and try to toggle fullscreen using the button, you'll see that it doesn't work...

Comment: You can only toggle-off fullscreen using javascript if you entered the fullscreen mode using javascript. I'm not sure why you decided to down-vote the answer. I'll add a note about this.